# hibernate Error : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.Query

Tags: java, hibernate

i try to devlope a small application with java and hibernate, when i run the test class of this application i get this error message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hibernate: insert into REUNION (TITREREUNION, DATEREUNION) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into REUNION (TITREREUNION, DATEREUNION) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into REUNION (TITREREUNION, DATEREUNION) values (?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl     cannot be cast to javax.persistence.Query
at metier.MetierImpl.getAllReunion(MetierImpl.java:62)
at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

as you see the error is class MetierImpl : the method that cause the error is :

```
 public Reunion getAllReunion(){

    Session session =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query req=(Query) session.createQuery("select R  from Reunion ");
    List<Reunion> list = req.getResultList();
    Reunion r=(Reunion) req.getResultList().get(0);

    return r;


}
```

Comment: can't you just remove the casting to (Query) at line (Query) session.createQuery("select R  from Reunion ");

Comment: when i remove the casting query it's an error, it forced me to add the casting

Comment: because you don't use the correct Query class, you should the one from hibernate instead of javax.persistence.Query

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate [Session.createQuery()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29) returns an instance of `org.hibernate.Query`. Your code  casts this object to `javax.persistence.Query`, but it's not an instance of `javax.persistence.Query`. So you get this exception.

Don't make this cast, and import the correct Query class: not `javax.persistence.Query`, but `org.hibernate.Query`.

Comment: and what about the return type  the org.hibernate.Query ??

Comment: What do you mean? A class doesn't have a return type. A method has a return type.

Comment: i need to have a list of Reunion in the return Type of methode getAllReunion(), like in javax.Persistance.Query  re.getResultList();

Comment: You're using Hibernate, but can't read javadoc? The method to use is `list()`, not `getResultList()`. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29